# Multiple bent arrow between same objects

Tags: tikz-cd

I'm trying to use the tikz-cd package to write the following diagram with multiple bent arrows between the same two objects, with horizontal dots between them.

[image]

My tikz-cd skills are not up to par here.  My feeble attempt so far is the following

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz-cd}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow[swap]{d} \\
    B \arrow[bend right = 70]{u} \arrow[bend right = 70, draw=none]{u}{\ldots} \arrow[bend right=120]{u}
    \end{tikzcd}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to properly format the code on this site.  If someone could correct me, hopefully I can figure out how!  Thanks.

Comment: To format code you can select the code and click the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: Select the code and hit Ctrl+K or click the button with `{}`. Blocks are indented with four spaces, inline code placed between backticks.

Comment: Please could you make your code compilable? That makes it much easier for people to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go:

> [image]

To add text to an arrow you just have to insert it between `"..."`. To put the text on the other side of the arrow, append a single quote, like this: `"..."'`.

I also changed a little how you draw the arrow. Instead of increasing the bend angle of `bend right` (or `bend left`), you can set the `looseness` parameter a little higher. It will look much more... loose `:)`.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[swap]{d} \\
B \arrow[bend right = 70, "\sigma_1", "\ldots"']{u}
  \arrow[bend right = 90, looseness=2, "\sigma_n"']{u}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: beautiful!  Thanks so much.  Yeah, I tried playing with the bending but it just looked absurd.  This solution with the looseness is perfect!

Comment: Although it doesn't seem to be compiling.  I don't think it likes the things in quotations.  Any idea what's up here?

Comment: Strange... It compiles for me. What version of tikzcd and LaTeX are you using? Are you compiling with other packages or does the code above alone throws the error?

Comment: It fails with just that code.  I'm using Latex2e, and I'm struggling to find what version of Tikz I'm using.  Perhaps I should just get the latest.

Comment: @Benighted To see which version of the packages you are using add the `\listfiles` command before your `\documentclass`. Then the .log file will have such list. Or, to see the version of `tikzcd` specifically you can open a command prompt and type `texdoc tikz-cd`.

Comment: My .log file says "Package: tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)."  But it is strange because I downloaded the latest version of pgf package and it's still giving me the error.  I'm very confused by this.

Comment: @Benighted Wow, that's... old. But did you update only Ti*k*Z? You should update both Ti*k*Z (all of PGF) _and_ `tikzcd`. Better yet, I recommend you update your whole TeX distribution.

Comment: Got the latest tikx-cd and it's still not working :(  Anyways, I clearly need to figure out somethings about my system soon.  Thanks so much for your help though!

Comment: You're welcome :) If you have problems updating your system you can always ask a question about it too.